# Replace whitespace(space) wit hdot in array

Tags: php

```
$testarray=array(
    'username'  => 'accname',
    'password'  => 'usrpswd',
};
```

And in accname I have white space between name and surname like John Doe i want to have John.Doe

I tried to do something like this

```
foreach ($testarray as $value)
{
    $value = $username;
    $value = str_replace(' ', '.', $value);
}
```

But it doesn't work, how should it look?

Comment: your `testarray` will contain only these two value?

Comment: Why not just `$testarray['username'] = str_replace(' ', '.', $testarray['username']);`?

Comment: it will works for every user? I have about 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Description** You may use the following code snippet for your query.That is make use of regex of finding spaces between strings while iterating on array. Assuming your array has the static/fixed keys.

**Code**

```
  $testarray = array(
    'username' => 'john doe',
    'password' => 'usrpswd'
  );

  foreach ($testarray as $key => $key_val) {
     // Use regex for finding any space between strings
     if ($key == "username") {
        if (preg_match('/\s/', $key_val)) {
            $testarray["username"] = str_replace(' ', '.', $key_val);
        }
     }
  }
```

Now the username key has the value "John.Doe".

Comment: I am taking usernames from other source like domain. I can do that 'username' => 'john doe'

Comment: i have used this array just as a sample data in order to understand the logic only. What ever you get from the source it will iterate and check for space in string if it there is any space it will replace it with the Dot (.) and echo it other wise just echo it.

Comment: although you have accepted the answer but i would say use my code snippet because it is more dynamic. Now it only depends on you :)

Comment: ?  Sorry, i am not getting you

Comment: I don't wanna display output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124772/discussion-between-ahmer-saeed-and-defus).

Answer (score 1):

replace foreach statement with [`pass by-ref`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach ($testarray as &$value)
```

and remove `$value = $username;` which seems unnecessary.

Or you can update it to use this (only updates username and keeps password as it is) -

```
foreach ($testarray as $key => &$value) {
  if ($key == 'username') {
    $value = str_replace(' ', '.', $value);
  }
}
```

If it only has one value (fixed array)

```
$testarray['username'] = str_replace(' ', '.', $testarray['username']);
```

Comment: If it's a fixed array as above, then there is no need for a loop. -> `$testarray['username'] = str_replace(" ", ".", $testarray['username']);`.

Comment: I want to change only username don't need to "touch" password or other elements

Comment: @Defus check the updated answer, use if loop for not touching password and use the second approach if array is fixed

Comment: my array isn't fixed I think 

Casue I have: <?php $testarray = array { 'one' => 'something'. 'one2' => 'something2' };